Suddenly can't edit my own answer
I suddenly can't edit my own answer post. I get this error message:

Comment Reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment.

I tried some more specific messages and also tried to re-login or use incognito, but still no luck.
Is this a bug?


The site says that you edited that answer about 4-5 minutes ago.

Yeah, after that I can no longer edit.

It looks like it just doesn't like your edit comment. Change that or delete it.

Oh well it works now. I swear I tried so many other messages. Emptying the edit message works though. I thought an edit message is required before?

.... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ...

An edit message is required when you edit someone else's question or answer up to a certain reputation level.

I have the same error on askubuntu.com when editing someones else's question. I even use a message I used before. Didn't get it working.

Now it is working again with exactely the same text in Edit Summary.
